# if mongodb match inside aggregation returns nothing, how to make a new query?

Tags: mongodb

I use match to select some documents from the collection, and then output all other documents except those found.
If match doesn't find any documents, then I need to display all available documents from the collection.
How can this be done?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Without an example I don't know if I've understood correctly, but you can try this aggregation query (or add this aggregation stages into your query).

The ide is using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) create two ways:

- Frist way: Match the value
- Second way: Get everything

And use `$project` to output one of these options using `$cond` and `$size`.
Into the `$project` if the array returned in the "exists way" is 0 (any result) the `result` is `no_exists`(i.e. all values) otherwise is the `exists` value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "exists": [
        {
          "$match": {
            // your match
          }
        }
      ],
      "no_exists": []
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "result": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              {
                "$size": "$exists"
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          "then": "$no_exists",
          "else": "$exists"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-ly67CqIBuQ) where value exists and output only the value, and [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/COnafy6hiut) where not exists and output all collection.